# Windows Explorer not responding when I access Downloads folder

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-8.1

I have a Dell XPS L502X running on a genuine Windows 8.1 installed 4 days ago. Everything is fine but what happened now is whenever I try to access my Downloads folder, Windows Explorer stops responding. Everything else runs fine. What do I do?

Comment: Do you have anything in your download folder that you mind losing? If not, I would just delete the folder, then remake it.

Comment: No. I don't. Okay. Will do that. And let you know if I run into more problems.

Comment: I would guess Explorer is trying to access the Registry entries about that folder, but fails to. Only way to be sure is through Process Monitor. You could copy the folder using cmd and see if that's the case.

Comment: I also had this and in my case the windows Defender was hogging 1 CPU core so much that the Explorer was terrible slow.

Answer (score 1):

If you have many files, it could be that the Windows is struggling to 'keep-up' so to speak. Happens to me when I open certain folders that are filled with executable files. The files have generic icons, after a couple of moments (minutes), it works nicely.

Do you have to restart Explorer or does it fix itself after a while? If the latter, you can delete the folder as Peter Maxwell says or hide some of the larger files.